# link_to ... remote: true, method: post always fails on first try

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a link_to using remote: true through POST on a specific feature that toggle it's state on click. However, everytime I try to toggle it, rails responds with a 404 only on the first try, but it works normally on the second try. The route is working and configured correctly, but no idea why the first click always returns 404. This is happening on Chrome and Firefox, production only, development works fine.

I'm using Rails 4.1 and Ruby 2.1.1p76, Unicorn + Nginx on Ubuntu

Here's the log message:

```
 I, [2014-09-07T07:51:27.251225 #18157]  INFO -- : Started POST "/u/alexandre/recommend/gigantes-de-aco-e-pontas-soltas" for 101.138.232.14 at 2014-09-07 07:51:27 +0000
F, [2014-09-07T07:51:27.254116 #18157] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/u/alexandre/recommend/gigantes-de-aco-e-pontas-soltas"):
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  unicorn (4.8.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:576:in `process_client'
  unicorn (4.8.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:670:in `worker_loop'
  unicorn (4.8.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:525:in `spawn_missing_workers'
  unicorn (4.8.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:536:in `maintain_worker_count'
  unicorn (4.8.3) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:294:in `join'
  unicorn (4.8.3) bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `load'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `<main>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'


I, [2014-09-07T07:51:31.251047 #6505]  INFO -- : Started POST "/u/alexandre/recommend/gigantes-de-aco-e-pontas-soltas" for 101.138.232.14 at 2014-09-07 07:51:31 +0000
I, [2014-09-07T07:51:31.254408 #6505]  INFO -- : Processing by UsersController#recommend as JS"/u/alexandre/recommend/gigantes-de-aco-e-pontas-soltas" for 101.138.232.14 at 2014-09-07 07:51:31 +0000
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :users, :param => :id, constraints: {id: /.*/}, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update], path: "u" do
    post "/recommend/:text_id/" => "users#recommend", as: "recommend"
end
```

**_bookshelf_actions.html.haml**

```
%ul#bookshelf-actions
  %li#recommend.is-action.text-center
    %span#recommendation-count.count= text.recommendations_count
    = link_to '', recommend_url , remote: true, method: :post, id: "recommend-btn", class: 'reader-social-icon social-action is-recommend', data: {recommended: recommended}
    %span#recommendation-status.action-name= t(:recommend, count: @current_user ? (@current_user.recommended?(text) ? 1 : 0) : 0)
```

**text.js.coffee**

```
@text.actions.recommend.on 'ajax:success', (e, data) ->
    self.text.actions.recommend.attr 'data-recommended', data.recommended
    $('#recommendation-status').text data.status
    $('#recommendation-count').text data.counter
    return
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def recommend
    text = Text.friendly.find(params[:text_id])
    @user.recommend(text)
    respond_to do |format|
      status = I18n.t(:recommend, count: @user.recommended?(text) ? 1 : 0)
      text.reload
      counter = text.recommendations_count
      format.json {render json: {status: status, recommended: @user.recommended?(text), counter: counter}, status: :ok}
    end
  end
```

I have googled around and haven't found nothing about this problem or something similar. Any help will be really appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: do you see any error in browsers console? Also in your logs you are getting error ActionController::RoutingError

Comment: Did you set up the server yourself? You're using Unicorn - do you have any of the logs from this?

Comment: maybe your routes has problem. try `member do post "/recommend/:text_id/" => "users#recommend", as: "recommend" end` in resources

Comment: Browser console shows 404 not found. Yes, I set up the server myself, the logs are ok

Comment: @KienThanh suggestion worked. Do you have an explanation for this? (Also, can you turn it into an answer, so I can mark it as accepted? ;)

Comment: @AlexandreWiechersVaz yes, I did :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your routes has problem, I have not found document which place a route without `member` or `collection` in resources. With your config routes, the link maybe match:

`u/recommend/:text_id`

So you should use:

```
member do 
  post "/recommend/:text_id/" => "users#recommend", as: "recommend" 
end
```

in your resources routes.

I think it has error because the routes missed id of users resources. Using `member do ... end` will match your expect routes:

`/u/:id/recommend/:text_id`